# Как "искусственно" сделать функцию await?

Tags: c#, async-await

У меня есть "заданный свыше" (в API) шаблон функции

```
    public async Task SaveAsync( MyType val ){ ... }
```

я напсиал реализацию, но у меня внутри *строго синхронный* код. Код все делает как надо, в смысле - сохраняет.

Но я не могу скомпилировать проект целиком из за ошибки

```
This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. 
Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, 
or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread
```

Как можно с этим бороться?

Comment: Вы уверены, что дело в этом? Ведь указанный вами текст - это [предупреждение CS1998](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/43e4950a65961e2194e4ce082d64bc31#:~:text=to%20return%20%27Task%27%3F-,CS1998,-Warning), а предупреждения не влияют на процесс сборки (если конечно вы не настроили так студию).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - спасибо, я это подозревал, но, похоже, при коммите срабатывают какие то дополнительные правила

Comment: Быть может вам код на асинхронный лучше переписать? Вы же что-то куда-то сохраняете, верно? Покажите код.

Answer (score 3):

Строго говоря, приведённое вами предупреждение ошибкой компиляции не является, и его можно прямо так и оставить. Можете подавить его через [pragma warning disable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#pragma-warning) если знаете что делаете. Но я бы не рекомендовал так делать.

---

Писать строго синхронный код внутри асинхронного метода плохо, поскольку вы нарушаете один из подразумеваемых контрактов асинхронных методов - то, что они вернут управление "быстро", и особенно важно соблюдать это соглашение когда вы пишете точку расширения для чужого кода. **Поэтому лучше всего всё-таки переписать код на асинхронный вариант.** Если же по той или иной причине асинхронный метод написать не удаётся - вы можете использовать Task.Run чтобы запустить свой синхронный код в пуле потоков.

Однако, сам по себе Task.Run обладает тем недостатком, что он упускает так называемое обратное давление: если ваш метод будет вызываться чаще чем система сможет его обрабатывать, то в памяти будут неограниченно копиться задачи вплоть до исчерпания ресурсов (памяти). Поэтому совместно с Task.Run лучше использовать настраиваемые асинхронные семафоры для управления обратным давлением.

*Отмечу, что семафор не является окончательным решением проблемы обратного давления, но он, по крайней мере, не хуже синхронного варианта*

Таким образом, в общем случае ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```cs
private /*static*/ readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(…);
public async Task SaveAsync( MyType val ) {
   await semaphore.WaitAsync();
   try {
       await Task.Run(() => {
           // тут пишите ваш синхронный код
       });
   } finally {
       semaphore.Release();
   }
}
```

Теперь немного слов о времени жизни семафора и о его инициализации.

Семафор должен быть общий для всех ограничиваемых запросов! Иначе он просто не имеет смысла. Проще всего добиться этого объявив его статическим, но этот вариант не позволит использовать внедрение зависимостей для его инициализации, как и делить запросы на несколько пулов.

Поэтому лучше будет, если вы аккуратно отследите время жизни того класса, в котором семафор расположен. К примеру, при использовании стандартного DI из ASP.NET Core вы можете объявить этот сервис как Singleton. Если же это невозможно, поскольку другой модуль требует другого времени жизни - всегда можно вынести метод SaveAsync или хотя бы семафор в отдельный синглтон-сервис.

Теперь про инициализацию. Для CPU-bound задач (т.е задач, которые не выполняют никакого ввода-вывода) надо использовать начальное значение для семафора равное [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount?view=net-6.0). А вот для IO-bound задач такого идеального значения нет, и это значение надо подбирать исходя из возможностей той системы, с которой вы взаимодействуете. И желательно выносить его в конфиг, чтобы при изменении параметров "железа" не потребовалась пересборка.

Кстати, если вдруг у вас в методе встретятся вместе CPU-bound и IO-bound код - не стесняйтесь разнести их по разным семафорам:

```cs
await cpuBound.WaitAsync();
try {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        // тут пишите ваш CPU-bound код
    });
} finally {
    cpuBound.Release();
}

await ioBound.WaitAsync();
try {
    // на самом деле второй Task.Run в свежих версиях .NET тут можно не добавлять
    // но и мешать он тоже не будет
    await Task.Run(() => {
        // тут пишите ваш синхронный IO-bound код
    });
} finally {
    ioBound.Release();
}
```

Также имеет смысл разделять IO-bound код, обращающийся к разным ресурсам.

Comment: Я бы завернул семафор в класс с методом Take(): Task<IDisposable> и назвал его AsyncLock (чем он по сути и является)

Comment: @VladD да, так можно сделать, но это не обязательно

Comment: Не обязательно, конечно, но чтобы не дублировать try/finally…

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы избежать этой ошибки (или всё же предупреждения?) можно поместить такую конструкцию в тело функции:

```
await Task.CompletedTask;
```

Она удобна именно для подобных случаев - когда вам нужно написать асинхронную функцию, но вам пока нечего в ней ожидать. В дальнейшем вы сможете добавить реальное ожидание каких-то асинхронных задач, а эту заглушку убрать.

P.S. Если вы что-то куда-то сохраняете, то это наверняка `IO-bound` задача, посмотрите, может то, чем вы пользуетесь для сохранения, уже имеет асинхронные методы, которыми вы можете воспользоваться.

Comment: Билдить машину состояний без причины - жрать ресурсы попусту. Не успеешь оглянуться как у тебя весь код будет в таких бесполезных заглушках. Если код в методе синхронный - не надо никаких `async` добавлять. А потом проще воткнуть ключевое слово в сигнатуру метода, чем искать, где же там закопан этот бесполезный `await` и через пару лет вспоминать "а что же я курил, когда это писал". Как итог - вы советуете плохую практику.

Comment: @aepot Насколько я понял, это всё-таки заданное автору ограничение, он не может менять сигнатуру функции. Но так то вы по-своему тоже правы, конечно. Просто у меня было в практике, что проект постепенно переписывался на асинхронную версию и реально нужно было методы сделать асинхронными сначала чисто формально, а потом они переписывались под на самом деле асинхронные, так что это вполне себе реальная практика из реальной жизни.

Comment: Ключевое слово `async` не меняет сигнатуру метода. Такие дела. Убрал минус, удалил свой ответ. Потому что здесь действительно стоит сначала разобраться в ситуации, а потом решать, как поступить правильно. Я лишь исходил из соображений, что генерить машину состояний впустую крайне не стоит того.